# Allow access via reverse proxy by http referer

Tags: apache2, reverse-proxy, http-referer

I've just been given an apache2 reverse proxy server to look after. I've been asked to set up access a gis system using https which is all fine. I want to know if there's any way of configuring the vhost so it only allows access if the http header referer is as specified by me? I.e if the http header to access the gis system doesn't have the right referer, the rproxy denies access.

I'm trying:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(.*?)\.?(mydomain\.co\.uk|mydomain\.com) (\/?.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.mydomain.co.uk/not_allowed_here.html [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I got there in the end:

```
> SetEnvIf Referer
> ^https?:\/\/[^.]+\.(?>mydomain\.co\.uk|mydomain\.com).*$ refererok
> 
> <Location />
>     order deny,allow
>     deny from all </Location>
> 
> <Location /set2/>
>     order deny,allow
>     allow from all </Location>
> 
> <Location /set1/>
>     order deny,allow
>     deny from all
>         allow from env=refererok </Location>
```

Comment: is this even valid? it seems that your Location tags are self-closing, instead of having content